# Is it better to say "a unique shared interest" or "a specific shared interest" of a group of people?

Tags: word-choice

For example: The interior of a home is a unique, shared interest of the people living in it. Or: The interior of a home is a specific, shared interest of the people living in it.
Another example:The the roads in a village are a (specific or unique), shared interest of the villages.
Meaning that for the most part all and only the villagers are interested in the roads being in good shape, because most villagers traverse most roads often, while outsiders rarely drive around the village.

Comment: We sometimes use [common²](https://www.lexico.com/definition/common) to describe  something that is shared. "Their common interest..."

Comment: _Unique_ means _the only one of its kind_, so it depends on whether you mean that the topic is the only interest which those people have in common.

Comment: *Unique* definitely seems a bit strong for these examples, unless the interior is very special (you say "outsiders rarely drive" which suggests outsiders may have some interest). It's not clear exactly what you mean: just that nobody else is interested, or that it's their only interest, or the only interest they have in common.

Comment: It seems unlikely that a group of people living in the same house or village have only one common interest. And in the example about outsiders, the rarity of their visits does not mean they won't care about the state of the road when they get there. So 'unique' is a poor choice of word.

Comment: The villagers share an interest in the local roads, and those who live outside this particular area do not share that interest.  (Which seems pretty obvious to me....)